# Migrating from Windows Authentication to Azure AD authentication for Asp.net MVC website hosted in IIS

Tags: azure-active-directory, iis-7, azure-authentication

I am migrating my ASP.Net MVC based website to use Azure AD Authentication. My website is successfully migrated to used AAD.

My website makes call to WCF service. How do I pass logged in information to this WCF service?

Here is my ServiceModel configuration in web.config. Appreciate your help

<system.serviceModel>

> ```
> <behaviors>
>   <endpointBehaviors>
>     <behavior name="AdsPlusValidatorServiceBehavior">
>       <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
>     </behavior>
>   </endpointBehaviors>
> </behaviors>
> <bindings>
>   <basicHttpBinding>
>     <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IJobManagerService" closeTimeout="00:01:00" OpenTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" ostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"  essageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"  allowCookies="false">
>       <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
>       <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
> ```

```
 >        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
>       </security>
```

> ```
>  </binding>
>  </basicHttpBinding>
> ```

```
 </bindings>
```

> ```
> <client>
>  <endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/Validator/Service" behaviorConfiguration="AdsPlusValidatorServiceBehavior" binding="basicHttpBinding"  bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IJobManagerService"contract="IJobManagerService"  name="BasicHttpBinding_IJobManagerService">
>     <identity>
>       <servicePrincipalName value="" />
>     </identity>
>   </endpoint>
> </client>   </system.serviceModel>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

take a look to [Using AAL to Secure Calls to a Classic WCF Service](https://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2012/12/17/using-aal-to-secure-calls-to-a-classic-wcf-service-2/). Replace AAL code with [MSAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet#using-msalnet).